# Minimal path in given graph

Tags: graph-theory

A graph is listed below:

[image]

The minimal cycle length has to be calculated with each edge to be traverse once or more than once

The cycle is not Eulerian in the graph as not all vertices of graph have even degree. My approach to the problem was getting odd vertex and counting the common edge from them. This was added to number of edges in the graph which is 24+4=28 so the minimal cycle length is 28.

Can you please let me know if the approach to the given problem is correct?

Comment: what do you mean? the minimal cycle is a square.

Comment: sorry my bad I have edited the question each edge has to be traversed and it can be done more than once

Comment: Seems logical in this particular case. By [Euler's Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eulerian_path), if you removed the four edges connecting the eight nodes of odd degree, you would have a graph with an Eulerian cycle. Add a back and forth traversal of the four relevant edges and you have a path that fits the bill. That's not exactly a proof that $28$ is minimal though.

Comment: *Chinese postman problem*

Comment: @DavidDiaz Thank you

Comment: @RobPratt hank you